# Change view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I'm new to coding so I followed this easy tutorial https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html

It all worked fine but I would like to change so there is no /news folder anymore and instead show all these news on welcome/index, how can I do so? And what code to modify in the tutorial?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create new route in application/config/routes.php. Or more simlpe: change route /news on /welcome/index

Comment: Yes but should I put any code on welcome.php?Because now nothing is showing. I have changed to '$route['news'] = 'welcome/index';'

Comment: Please read this
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=routing

You will understand how it s work.